# Adding units to frame label

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I have this code:

```
Clear[r,\[Lambda],ref,c];
ft[\[Rho]_]=(((1-ref^2)/(Pi*ref))^2+(\[Rho]^4/(\[Lambda]*r^3))^2)^(-1/2);
\[Lambda]=685*10^-9;r=25*10^-3;c=3*10^8;ref=0.995;
p1=Plot[ft[\[Rho]*10^-3],{\[Rho],0,1},PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,350}},PlotTheme- 
>"Monochrome",PlotStyle->Blue, FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Automatic}, {Automatic, 
Automatic}},Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}},FrameTicksStyle -> 
Directive[16, FontFamily -> "Times"],AspectRatio->1/2,ImagePadding ->{{60, 
60}, {50, 10}},FrameLabel -> {{Style[Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF],t], 
16,FontFamily -> "Times"],None},{Style["\[Rho] (mm)", 16,FontFamily -> 
"Times"],None}},ImageSize->400];
p2=LogPlot[(c/(4*r*ft[\[Rho]*10^-3]))/10^6,{\[Rho],0,1},PlotRange->{{0,1}, 
{0,350}},PlotTheme->"Monochrome",PlotStyle->Red, FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, 
Red}, {Automatic, Automatic}},Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, 
False}},FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},FrameTicksStyle -> 
Directive[16, FontFamily -> "Times"],AspectRatio->1/2,ImagePadding ->{{60, 
60}, {50, 10}},FrameLabel -> {{None,Rotate[Style[Subscript[\[CapitalDelta] \ 
[Nu] ,m] , 16,FontFamily -> "Times"],180 Degree]},{None,None}},ImageSize- 
>400];
Overlay[{p1,p2}]
```

Which generates this graph:

[image]

I want the red frame label to show as $\Delta\nu_{m}$ (MHz). How can I add the units without messing up the subscript?

Comment: You can use `Row[{Subscript[...],...}]` for that (see the documentation of [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) for more details)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lukas Lang points out, `Row` will allow you to achieve the label you want. Here is the code. Note that I have rewritten parts of it to make it simpler.

```
λ = 685.*^-9; r = 25.*^-3; c = 3.*^8; ref = 0.995;
ft[ρ_] = (((1 - ref^2)/(π ref))^2 + (ρ^4/(λ r^3))^2)^(-1/2);
p1 =
  Plot[ft[ρ 10^-3], {ρ, 0, 1},
    AspectRatio -> 1/2,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 350}},
    PlotStyle -> Blue,
    FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[16, "TR"],
    FrameLabel ->
      Transpose[{Style[#, 16, "TR"] & /@ {Subscript[ℱ, t], "ρ (mm)"}, {None, None}}],
    ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {50, 10}},
    ImageSize -> 400];
p2 =
  LogPlot[(c/(4 r ft[ρ 10^-3]))/10^6, {ρ, 0, 1},
    AspectRatio -> 1/2,
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}},
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[16, "TR"],
    FrameLabel ->
      {{None, Rotate[Style[Row[{Subscript[Δν, m], " (MHz)"}], 16, "TR"], 180 Degree]},
       {None, None}},
    ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {50, 10}},
    ImageSize -> 400];
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image: plot]

Note, in particular, the use of `"TR"`, a handy short form of `FontFamily -> "Times"`